# actionscript ExternalInterface namespace collisions

Tags: javascript, actionscript-2, namespaces, externalinterface, collision

A have a flash widget (a music player) and there are about 10 instances of it on one page. I need to communicate between the flash and the javascript of the page it's embedded in. I haven't done much with actionscript for a long time, but some googling led me [here](http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_15683), and to ExternalInterface. It seemed perfect, however there is one problem. I did something like this:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("stopTrack", this, stopTrack);
```

However, now stopTrack will be registered to 10 different things on the page. I want to be able to stop just one of the 10 tracks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't ENTIRELY remember -- but I seem to think that the callback isn't added to the window object, but the swf object on the page -- so somthing like

```
document.getElementById('musicFlashPlayer10').stopTrack();
```

would fire the callback on only that instance.

This format might change between browsers - in any case, the callback is added to each javascript instance the flash file is loaded for.